# Service fabric deploy failure in secure cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

I got following error when I try to use VSTS to deploy application to Azure secure cluster

An error occurred attempting to import the certificate. Ensure that your service endpoint is configured properly with a correct certificate value and, if the certificate is password-protected, a valid password. Error message: Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "Cannot find the requested object.

I copied certificate base64 string and password to Services Endpoint config. Should I do other option to let it work?

Comment: Do you use on premise build agent? Can you deploy/publish Service fabric through Visual Studio directly?

Comment: How do you get certificate base64 string?

Comment: I got the certificate base64 string by selecting corresponding KeyVault in azure > Secrets > Select certificate > Select Version > Click Show secret value and copy the value. I refered to this blog to create a self-signed certificate and add to KeyVault (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/)

Comment: @starain-MSFT I can deploy used VS, I used powershell to get base64 string. I used certificate which create by admin.

Comment: Try to get the value in the azure portal, selecting corresponding KeyVault in azure > Secrets > Select certificate > Select Version > Click Show secret value and copy the value.

Comment: @starain-MSFT, thank you I solved the problem, the url should use https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, the url in service endpoint should use https